# Pass String between 2 View Controllers in a Tab Bar

Tags: swift

I have a Swift App that uses Firebase. On this part of the app there are 2 VC's that are in a Tab Bar Controller then a Navigation Controller.  So TBC -> NavC -> VC.

I need to pass a string from the main TBC VC. It is a firebase ID for a card. Using that ID I can access all of the children on that card's node, but without it I am unable.

I have tried using prepareForSegue..

```
let tabVc = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
let navVc = tabVc.viewControllers!.first as! UINavigationController
let destinationVC = navVc.viewControllers.first as! MonthlyNutViewController

destinationVC.cardID = cardID
print(cardID)
```

I have set a breakpoint on that and it doesn't hit.

I have seen a few older SO posts suggesting that I create a global variable in the appDelegate, but I thought that was frowned upon.

What will be the best way for me to transfer that string?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's just one variable, I would go for the appDelegate.  You also have the option of creating a singleton to hold a more complex data model.

Just declare the variable in the `appDelegate`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var myFirebaseString : String?
```

and then access it from your ViewControllers

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.myFirebaseString = "key"
```

and then in the second controller

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
ley localKey = appDelegate.myFirebaseString
```